# Redirections class redirect PHP

Tags: php, class, redirect, cookies

I'm here because I've a problem I can't resolve myself, I'm trying to code with class, so I keep a code clean (first time i do that), And I've a problem, I've 3 level of permissions in my user, I want :

- If cookie is set : Redirect to the page which is the good one for his type (admin etc..)
- If session is set : Redirect to the page which is the good one for his type (admin etc..)
- If he want to go on a page and he is not connected or he don't have the right type, he is redirected to login.php

Here is what I did already :

```
<?php

/**
 * Redirect user in member area, or booster area, or admin area
 * See if cookies is here, if so, redirect user
 */

class Redirect{
private $host = 'http://localhost/testpoo'; // URL to redirect

/**
 * Redirect user if cookie, or session exist
 */
public function user()
{

    if(isset($_COOKIE['remember']))
    {
        // Verify if token exist
        $req = $db->prepare("SELECT token, type, id FROM users WHERE token = ?");
        $req->execute(array($_COOKIE['remember']));
        $cookie = $req->rowCount();

        if($cookie == 1)
        {
            // If cookie true
            $cookie = $req->fetch();
            $_SESSION['type'] = $cookie['type'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $cookie['id'];
        }
    }

    // If sessions exists we redirect user in function of the type 
    if(isset($_SESSION['type']))
    {
        $session = $_SESSION['type']; // Get type of user (admin, member, client)
        switch($session)
        {
            case 'member':
                header("Location:".$this->host."/panel/member/index.php");
                break;
            case 'client':
                header("Location:".$this->host."/panel/client/index.php");
                break;
            case 'admin':
                header("Location:".$this->host."/panel/dashboard/index.php");
                break;
        }

    }else{ // Else, redirect to login form
        header('Location:'.$this->host."/login.php");
        break;
    }
}


}


?>
```

The problem is, the else redirect on login.php everytime, because on login.php, I've also called this class, so when the customer come in the login page, if he have a cookie, or a login session, he go directly to where he need to be!

Thanks!

Comment: looks like your missing `session_start()`

Comment: It's initiated before I call the class in all my pages ^^

Comment: `$db` is undefined. PHP scope is not like JavaScript.

Comment: `var_dump($_SESSION);` see what it actually is

Comment: The problem isn't about sessions etc.. I need to find something to redirect user to the login.php (Where I also call this class, so the class redirect to Login.php etc.. etc... etc..)

Comment: then i have no idea what you are asking

Comment: I need to have a class that redirect users to his page, if he's admin : redirected to admin.php, if he's member : redirected to member.php;

Comment: And If the user isn't admin, and want to access to admin.php, he's redirected to his member.php or login.php if he's not connected